# How to enable ZabbixAgent2 loadable plugin?

Tags: linux, windows, zabbix, golang

I'm trying to write loadable plugin by [this manual](https://blog.zabbix.com/developing-plugins-for-zabbix-agent-2/9682/).
But when I test my plugin I get the message:

> myip [m|ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED] [Unknown metric myip]

[image: Error in CLI]

I tried to create metric on zabbix-server, but I don't know what `Key` value to set.

Did anybody have the same problems?